# ics attachment not reflected in outlook calendar using php?

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

I have used this function send `icalevent` to outlook calendar.

But this function works in gmail but not in outlook calendar. In outlook I am getting message alone. Please anyone tell me what is wrong with the code:

```
    \\ function to send icalevent to outlook calendar
    function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location){
      $domain = 'exchangecore.com';

    //Create Email Headers
    $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

    //Create Email Body (HTML)
    $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
    $message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";
    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

    $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
    'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
    'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
    'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
    'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
    'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
    'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
    'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
    'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
    'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
    'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
    'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
    'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
    'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
    'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
    'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
    'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
    'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
    'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
    'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
    'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
    'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
    'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
    'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
    'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;

    $mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);  

    return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
}

$from_name = "webmaster";        
$from_address = "info@sageit.in";        
$to_name = "Joseph";        
$to_address = "gopinathan@domain.com";        
$startTime = "11/6/2015 18:00:00";        
$endTime = "11/6/2015 19:00:00";        
$subject = "My Test Subject";        
$description = "My Awesome Description";        
$location = "Joe's House";
sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location);
  exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to remove the boundary from function. now the function is working fine

Change this to

```
 $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
```

To

// $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";